# How to decode hex values from a string in python

Tags: python, string, hex, decode

I am trying to decode the hex values inside my string so at the end I have one "readable" string.

For example:

```
encoded_string = 'videoplayback%253Fexpire%253D1532566750%2526mime%253Dvideo%25252Fmp4%2526key%253Dyt6%2526mt%253D1532544983%2526fvip%253D5%2526i'
```

Each hex value is indicated by a %-symbol and the length of the value can differentiate. 
What I tried is to decode the string manually:

```
encoded_string = encoded_string.replace('%253A', '\x25\x3A')
encoded_string = encoded_string.replace('%252F', '\x25\x2F')
encoded_string = encoded_string.replace('%253F', '\x25\x3F')
encoded_string = encoded_string.replace('%253D1532566750', '\x25\x3D\x15\x32\x56\x67\x50')
```

Now I need help with a function that is able to find the hex values and decode them.

*Thank you guys!*

Answer (score 2):

Too much work.

```
>>> urllib.parse.unquote(urllib.parse.unquote(encoded_string))
'videoplayback?expire=1532566750&mime=video%2Fmp4&key=yt6&mt=1532544983&fvip=5&i'
```

Comment: Didn't know about this! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions for that:

```
re.sub(
    r'%([A-F0-9]{4,14})',
    lambda m: str(int(m.groups()[0], 16)),
    encoded_string
)
```

Though I'm not sure if you just want to do URL decoding?

Comment: Yeah, i didn't know there were this option. Thank you

Comment: @DanielBörg Please note that this is something completely different than the URL unquoting done in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51528260/3767239). Here the hex strings you specified in the OP are taken as such and transformed to corresponding base 10 integer strings. Compare the results to make sure if it really is what you want.